# How to make a browser message popup jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how to make a css styled box pop up on load that tells you the browser you are using. I have the browser identification code, but I don't know how to make the popup appear on load.
Popup that's all I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Browser detect:

```
function myFunction() { if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) { alert('Opera'); } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) { alert('Chrome'); } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) { alert('Safari'); } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) { alert('Firefox'); } else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) //IF IE > 10 { alert('IE'); } else { alert('unknown'); } }
```

Comment: Do I need more code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { myFunction(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is, without using jQuery ui dialog and using only css to build the popup:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
    return'Opera';
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
    return 'Chrome';
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
    return 'Safari';
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
    return 'Firefox';
  } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) { //IF IE > 10
    return 'IE';
  }
  return 'unknown';
}
function popupClose() {
   $('#popup').hide();
}

$(function () {
  $('.content').text(myFunction());
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  visibility: visible;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background:slategray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div id="popup" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Browser</h2>
        <a class="close" href="javascript:popupClose();">×</a>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually like the css. Let me test it.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the blank screen after closing it?

Comment: Like, it goes blank white on my website.

Comment: Yah, I did. But how do you stop the blank background?

Comment: I did. It says thanks for the feedback. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: That didn't solve the white BG after closing the popup. Unless I was looking at something else.

Comment: That changed the box background, but the background of the entire webpage background stays white. I had a textured background on the original webpage, but the whole page goes white after closing the pop up.

Comment: sorry, I updated again the snippet. Could you retry?  For me is very late, so I go to sleep. It was an interesting challange with you. Thanks so much.

Comment: K. Welcome. Read this in the morning if it didn't work.

Comment: That changed the background before it was closed. Add this in the css: body {
  background: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/template-widescreen-background-pattern-html1.jpg");
}

Answer (score 0):

My popup function from:
https://jsfiddle.net/mm7b7t5t/

(Supports draggable popups, multiple buttons, forms, returns the button clicked etc etc)

With the following code:

```
var browserPopup = new popup([{text: "Close"}], "Browser", "<p>"+browserName()+"</p>");
browserPopup.open();

function browserName() {
  if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
    return'Opera';
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
    return 'Chrome';
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
    return 'Safari';
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
    return 'Firefox';
  } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) { //IF IE > 10
    return 'IE';
  }
  return 'unknown';
}
```